# Асинхронные запросы в Python

Tags: python, json, requests, aiohttp

имеется следующий фрагмент кода:

```
i = 1
while i <= len(data)-1:
    address_from_token = data[i]["Address"]
    k = 1
    while k <= len(data)-1:
        address_to_token = data[k]["Address"]
        if address_to_token != address_from_token:
            d = {'fromTokenAddress': address_from_token, 'toTokenAddress': address_to_token,
                'amount': 1000000000000000000}
            response = requests.get("https://api.1inch.exchange/v3.0/1/quote", params=d)
            r = response.json()
            print(r["toTokenAmount"], address_from_token, address_to_token)
        k = k+1
    i = i+1
```

Вопрос как запустить запрос асинхронно (то есть выполнять цикл, отправляя запросы, но не дожидаться их ответа перед запуском следующего) и выводить результаты "по готовности"

Понял что нужно использовать aiohttp, но не очень понимаю как записать асинхронный запрос так, чтобы в него передавался параметр из цикла.

UPD ------

Написал примерно в таком формате, но полагаю, что они все равно выстраиваются в очередь в рамках цикла

```
async def get_Pair():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        d = {'fromTokenAddress': address_from_token, 'toTokenAddress': address_to_token,
             'amount': 1000000000000000000}
        async with session.get('https://api.1inch.exchange/v3.0/1/quote', params=d) as response:
            #response = requests.get("https://api.1inch.exchange/v3.0/1/quote", params=d)
            r = await response.json()
            print(r["toTokenAmount"], address_from_token, address_to_token)
```